# on down arrow KeyPress, click event is getting fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

on down arrow keypress , click event is getting fired, event.keycode is undefined

```
$(".dropdown:not(.li-search) a.dropdown-toggle", ".navbar-collapse").on("click", function(event) {

    var target = $(this).attr("target");

    if (event.keyCode !== '40'){
      if (!$(".li-menu").is(":visible") && target === undefined) {
        location.href=this.href;
      } else {
        window.open(this.href, '_blank');
      }
    }
});
```

in this code i am trying to open main menu in new tab , but external link is getting open on **down arrow keypress**

Comment: add your html code also and don't forget to mention what plugins you are using?

Answer (score 1):

call preventDefault() function.

```
    $(".dropdown:not(.li-search) a.dropdown-toggle", ".navbar-collapse").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("target");
    if(event.keyCode!=='40'){
     if (!$(".li-menu").is(":visible") && target===undefined) {
       location.href=this.href;
    }
        else {
     window.open(this.href,'_blank');
     }
     }
});
```

See the keycode for the reference https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/
in order to configure your app for particular key event

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the classes `dropdown-toggle`, `navbar-collapse`, I'm guessing that you are using **Bootstrap** library.

If that is the case, the behaviour you are seeing is reasonable. Let's break down the issues:

1. **on down arrow keypress , click event is getting fired**

   Q: You have only bind the handler on `click` event so why are it is being triggered on `keypress`?
   A: Because this is a feature of bootstrap dropdown. To have better accessibilty, bootstrap triggers `click` event on the `keydown` of `up`, `down`, `esc` and `space` keys.
2. **event.keycode is undefined**

   Since it is a `click` event handler and not some keyboard event handler like `keydown` or `keypress`, `event.keyCode` should be `undefined`
3. **Note:** You are using a strict equality in the following condition

   `if (event.keyCode !== '40')`

   This will check both the type and value of the operands. Now, event.keyCode always return a `Number` while `'40'` is a string, hence the above condtion will yield `false` even if keyCode is 40. You should correct it to:

   `if (event.keyCode !== 40)`
4. Now, if you want to stop the redirect on down key, you should check whether the event triggered is an original event or was triggered by some js logic. For this, you may choose jQuery's `event.isTrigger` or `event.originalEvent`

Here's a code snippet:

```
$(".dropdown:not(.li-search) a.dropdown-toggle", ".navbar-collapse").on("click", function(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr("target");
    // Check if NOT an triggered event
    if (!event.isTrigger) {
        if (!$(".li-menu").is(":visible") && target === undefined) {
            location.href = this.href;
        } else {
            window.open(this.href, '_blank');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanx a lot mate , 
if (!event.isTrigger) worked , 
i liked the way you have answered my question . ThankU

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` tags will fire the click event when you press enter on them. However you will not have a `keyCode` on the event because it is not a `Key*` event. If you want to know the `keyCode` add a `keyDown` or `keyUp` handler as well. You could also handle both by doing something like the following:

```
$(".dropdown:not(.li-search) a.dropdown-toggle", ".navbar-collapse").on("click keydown", function(event) {

    var target = $(this).attr("target");
    if(event.type === 'keydown' && event.keyCode!=='40'){
       if (!$(".li-menu").is(":visible") && target===undefined) {
           location.href=this.href;
       }
       else {
           window.open(this.href,'_blank');
       }
   }
});
```

You'll probably also want to add an `event.preventDefault();` in there if you wish to prevent default browser behaviour from taking place.